# Can't use object methods of SOAP object with SOAP::Lite

Tags: perl, soap, jira, soaplite

I am reading data from our Jira via SOAP and recieve an array of `RemoteIssue`-Objects. Now I want to iterate over these and get the status of each ticket. The [documentation](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemoteIssue.html) of RemoteIssue says that there is a `getStatus()`-Method. When I call it on the objects my program throws an error.

Some code:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->uri($soap_uri)->proxy($soap_proxy);
my $login = $soap->login( $soap_user, $soap_password)->result;

if ($login) {
    # This works
    my $issues = $soap->getIssuesFromJqlSearch( $login, "project = \"$project\" AND fixVersion = \"$project_version\"", 500 );

    if ($issues) {
        foreach my $issue (@{$issues->result}) {
            my $foo = $issue->getStatus(); # This doesn't work
            print Dumper $foo;
        }
    }
}
$soap->logout();
```

The thrown error:

`Can't locate object method "getStatus" via package "RemoteIssue" at D:\ZeuS\lib/ZeuS.pm line 81`

Every other object method doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you're under the impression that you're receiving the Java object that you would manipulate on a Java consumer.

Unless `$issue->getStatus()` is a SOAP call (which I don't think it is) you're not dealing with the API, you're dealing with `SOAP::Lite`'s representation in Perl of the response in XML.

`getIssuesFromJqlSearch` seems to be the remote call. From that, you should get `$issues` as a [`SOAP::SOM`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP%3a%3aSOM) object. Which you then properly address with the [`result`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP%3a%3aSOM#result) method.

This will have whatever methods are defined for the class this object is blessed into.

To see what all this object responds to try this:

```
use mro ();
use Scalar::Util qw<blessed>;
...
    foreach my $issue (@{$issues->result}) {
        say '$issue ISA ('
          . join( ',', @{ mro::get_linear_isa( blessed( $issue )) } )
          . ')'
          ;
          ...
    }
```

`$issue` will only have those methods that have been defined for it on the Perl side.

- **NOTE:** It is not clear from your code where `ZeuS.pm` comes into this thing.

Comment: ZeuS.pm is the module where the code comes from. Ok, looks like I completely missunderstood the usage of SOAP::Lite. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Ok. I read a bit more documentation about SOAP::Lite, but I still can't figure out how to use the methods of a returned object. Could you help me eventually?